# PHP Code for calendar management (Google, iCloud, Exchange)

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api, exchange-server, icloud

I would like to realize:

- Get events of a calendar (Google, iCloud or Exchange)n
- A "2-way-Synchronisation" - thats means: if I add, change or delete an event in my calendar, this should be apply to the cloud calendar - and other way the same

I don't found a solution for me in the internet.
I hope you can support me - thanks a lot !

Comment: the problem is that i found no example code. for example the google calendar api. I downloaded the google php client api - and than ? no php code, which shows me, how I get events from a chosen calendar oO

Comment: Ghost108: Hello, I have published an answer that I believe may be of your interest. Please check it out and let me know whether you need anything else related to the Google Calendar API. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In order to get started with using the Google Calendar API client for PHP, you can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) comprehensive quickstart. It will walk you through the steps to create a PHP script that reads the events on your primary Google Calendar.

You can also find more information about the API and how to use the different options it offers [in this link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts).

I'd also like to suggest you visit the [Stackoverflow question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to help you create better questions, so that you can obtain the help and support that you need the easiest and fastest possible way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I found the QuickStart.php example, too. But this example can only run as command line. But I would like to use it in my browser.

Comment: @Ghost108 In that case, you may be interested in checking out the Javascript version of the Quickstart: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js

Comment: Thanks again ! It is very important for me, that I working with a php solution (without command line). is there no example ?

Comment: @Ghost108 If what you mean is that you are working on a PHP solution and you cannot interact with it (OAuth prompt) you can use a service account to interact with the google APIs (see this link: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts). Is this your issue? Cheers